# Neo4j Community Edition out of the box peformance on Windows

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and find that the query time is quite high compared to MySQL.

In presentations I hear about 2ms query times but I am getting **80 ms** even for the simplest query from the Movie Graph tutorial.
With other (very small) datasets I get query times around **150-250 ms**.

How do I get better performance with Neo4j?

I am using **Neo4j Server 2.0.1** Community Edition Stable Release in binary form (zip) on a Windows 8 laptop with 8GB RAM, SSD, i5. Queries are executed from the browser interface.

```
MATCH (tom {name: "Tom Hanks"}) RETURN tom
Returned 1 row in 189 ms

MATCH (tom {name: "Tom Hanks"}) RETURN tom
Returned 1 row in 79 ms
```

Analogous query in MySQL (InnoDB) is around 4 ms:

```
SET PROFILING=1;
SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = "Tom Hanks";
SHOW PROFILES;

+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
| Query_ID | Duration   | Query                                         |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
|        1 | 0.00369300 | SELECT * FROM person WHERE name = "Tom Hanks" |
+----------+------------+-----------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am getting a startup error (exception) when executing `Neo4j.bat`. Could that be the problem?

```
Can't load log handler "java.util.logging.FileHandler"
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for data/log/neo4j.%u.%g.log
```

Comment: As Michael mentioned in his answer, you should be using indexes, with labels. I just wanted to clarify that your *analogous* query in MySQL is not really analogous. With your MySQL query, you're hitting a `Person` table, with only `Person` entities. With your current Neo4j query, you're sifting through *all* nodes (significantly more nodes than the number of `Person`s.

Comment: You are right, my bad. My intention was to query using the label `(tom:Person ...)`. The query time is then down to 65 ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to create an index for

```
create index on :Person(name);
```

and use your query like this:

```
MATCH (tom:Person {name: "Tom Hanks"}) RETURN tom
```

Please note that the browser measures much more than just the query there are additional roundtrips for loading visualization data and other information.

For me in the browser that results in:

```
Returned 1 row in 38 ms
```

If I execute your query on my machine, but using the neo4j-shell (you can also access the web-version of it with `http://localhost:7474/webadmin`), I get instead:

```
$ match (n:Person {name:"Tom Hanks"}) return n;
==> +--------------------------------------+
==> | n                                    |
==> +--------------------------------------+
==> | Node[71]{name:"Tom Hanks",born:1956} |
==> +--------------------------------------+
==> 1 row
==> 1 ms
```

Comment: Thanks!
Without index the query takes 20-30ms in the web console (first execution always takes much longer though); with index it takes 1-4ms.
In the command line shell, however, the query appears to be slower at 15-20ms for some reason.

Comment: Probably more roundtrip involved as the shell uses RMI to communicate with the server.